# How can i get something out of a table so i can use it to extract other data from a table?

Tags: php

hello i have a problem with my code. I am trying to get klantid out of one of my tables so i can use it to extract info from an other table. but i have been trying for a long time and have no idea what it could be. hopefuly someone knows how to fix it.

```
$autotype = $_POST["autotypevak"];
require_once "gar-connect.php";
$autos = $conn->prepare ("select   autokenteken,
                                   automerk,
                                   autotype,
                                   autokmstand,
                                   klantid
                          from     auto
                          where    autotype = :autotype") ;
$autos->execute (["autotype" => $autotype]) ;
$klantid = $autos->fetch(["klantid"]);
$klanten = $conn->prepare ("select  klantid,
                                    klantnaam,
                                    klantadres,
                                    klantpostcode,
                                    klantplaats
                            from    klant
                            where   klantid = :klantid") ;
$klanten->execute (["klantid" => $klantid]);
```

Comment: Why don't you use a join jnstead?

Comment: i am new to coding so i dont really know what you mean

Comment: At this point, 5 minutes in the company of any basic, introductory guide to MySQL would be useful

Comment: What kind of object does $conn refer to?

Comment: it referes to gar-connect

Comment: gar-connect.php must contain custom code. Please elaborate. For example, what does get_class($conn) return?

Comment: this is the code in gar-connect  $servername = "localhost" ;
 $dbname = "garage" ;
 $username = "root" ;
 $password = "" ;

 try
 {
    $conn = new PDO ("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",
                     $username, $password) ;

    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION) ;
     //echo "Connectie is gelukt <hr />" ;

 }


 catch(PDOException $e)
 {
     echo "Connectie mislukt: " . $e->getMessage() ;
 }

Comment: Ah, now I know you're using PDO to connect to a MySQL database. What does execute() return?

Comment: The function execute() should return boolean TRUE and the parameter for fetch() should be the fetch mode like `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php.

Comment: i have no idea what you mean. my teacher kind of threw me in the deep

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this:

```
SELECT klantid, klantnaam,klantadres,klantpostcode,klantplaats
FROM klant k
INNER JOIN `auto` a ON k.klantid = a.klantid
WHERE autotype = :autotype
```

Your problem is probably from the first `FROM`. `auto` is a keyword and when you select from that table, you have to use `` ` `` to surround it.

Comment: One reason not to use this is data overhead. For each customer, the car information is duplicated. Also `klantid` is ambiguous without a table reference.

Comment: I don't see AUTO in the list of MySQL reserved keywords at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html ?

Comment: auto is the name of the table i want to get klantid from